# Работа со вложенными Generic - типами

Tags: c#, классы, generics

Доброго времени суток.

Есть Класс.

```
/// <summary>
/// Класс, являющийся "Номер Телефона".
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">Тип, в котором хранится Тип Номера Телефона.</typeparam>
// Кстати string не может быть ограничителем.

public class TelNumber<T> where T : string 
{
    /// <summary>
    /// ID Номер Телефона.
    /// </summary>
    public int TelNumberID { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Тип Номер Телефона.
    /// </summary>
    public TypeTelNumber<int,T> TypeTelNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Я хочу, чтобы тип телефона мог быть мог быть либо string, либо `TypeTelNumber<I,T>`.

Пишу так:

```
/// <summary>
/// Класс, являющийся "Номер Телефона".
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">Тип, в котором хранится Тип Номера Телефона.</typeparam>
public class TelNumber<T> where T : string, TypeTelNumber<I,T>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// ID Номер Телефона.
    /// </summary>
    public int TelNumberID { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Тип Номер Телефона.
    /// </summary>
    public T TypeTelNumber { get; set; }
}
```

**Вопрос:** Ругается на I, мол не такого типа (понятно и логично). Но как тогда сделать задуманное?

Comment: невозможно накладывать ограничения _ИЛИ_, можно только _И_

Comment: @Grundy не понял. Я накладываю ограничения на класс. Не может же быть T одновременно string и TypeTelNumber<I,T>(поэтому пишу ИЛИ). Могу правда сказать еще так: " Мой T может быть и string, и TypeTelNumber<I,T>"

Comment: _Не может же быть T одновременно string и TypeTelNumber<I,T>_ именно, но такая запись `string, TypeTelNumber<I,T>` расценивается именно как класс T должен быть _**И** string **И** TypeTelNumber<I,T>_

Comment: @Grundy Опана. Спасибо.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ваш код `where T : string` означает, что `Т` может быть *только* `string`, поскольку класс `System.String` [объявлен как `sealed`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx).

Чтобы скомпилировалось, достаточно объявить параметр `I`:

```
public class TelNumber<I, T> where T : string, TypeTelNumber<I,T>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// ID Номер Телефона.
    /// </summary>
    public int TelNumberID { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Тип Номер Телефона.
    /// </summary>
    public T TypeTelNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Но это не то, что вам нужно: в C# нет discriminated union-типов. Код `where T : string, TypeTelNumber<I,T>` означает, что `T` должен быть одновременно *и* `string`, *и* `TypeTelNumber<I,T>`. А поскольку `string` есть `sealed`, это означает, что ваш код не скомпилируется ни с каким типом.

Имеет смысл объявить просто два отдельных класса, реализующих общий интерфейс.

```
interface class ITelNumber<T>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// ID Номер Телефона.
    /// </summary>
    int TelNumberID { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Тип Номер Телефона.
    /// </summary>
    T TypeTelNumber { get; set; }
}

class StringTelNumber : ITelNumber<string>
{
    public int TelNumberID { get; set; }
    public string TypeTelNumber { get; set; }
}

class CustomTelNumber<I, T> : ITelNumber<TypeTelNumber<I, T>>
{
    public int TelNumberID { get; set; }
    public TypeTelNumber<I, T> TypeTelNumber { get; set; }
}
```

А ограничения на типы налагать уже вашей бизнес-логикой, а не системой типов: в C# система типов такого (пока) не умеет.

Comment: Но иногда хотелось бы, чтобы можно было указывать: этот или этот или этот :)

Comment: Там, кстати, про это никаких предложений не видно?

Comment: _Чтобы скомпилировалось, достаточно объявить параметр I_ - либо специфицировать его, например как в вопросе с помощью `int`

Comment: @Grundy Ну, я тоже к этому пришел, но очень захотелось сделать совсем обобщенный класс)). Наверно просто не буду ставить ограничений пока. Если будут проблемы, переделаю.

Comment: @VladD Прекрасно. Его и использую.

Comment: @Grundy: Было, но пока заглохло.

Answer (score 2):

Как ответили в комментариях, пока задуманного сделать нельзя, ибо мой первый кусок означает И, а не ИЛИ.

### Вариант 1

Сделать, как в моем варианте.

### Вариант 2

Не ставить ограничений, т.е

```
/// <summary>
/// Класс, являющийся "Номер Телефона".
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">Тип, в котором хранится Тип Номера Телефона.</typeparam>
public class TelNumber<T> 
{
    /// <summary>
    /// ID Номер Телефона.
    /// </summary>
    public int TelNumberID { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Тип Номер Телефона.
    /// </summary>
    public T TypeTelNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Во втором варианте появляется проблема, что я не могу контролировать какой тип используется для хранения типа. Ну и ладно((

### Вариант 3

Сделать так, как предложил VladD в ответе. Именно это вариант я и использую.